# Setting obj model material to wireframe

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am facing a problem when trying to change the material of an obj model to wireframe, this causes the scene to stop all its controls and logs this error message : "o.position is undefined"as a three.js error, below is an example of what I am trying to do:

`<a-obj-model src="#model-obj" material="wireframe:true" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct. The error could potentially be because of a missing geometry attribute.

Here's a working example:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-obj-wireframe

Adding a basic geometry makes the error go away:

```
<a-obj-model src="#obj" 
             position="0 1 -2"
             scale=".5 .5 .5"
             material="wireframe: true;"
             geometry="primitive: box;">
</a-obj-model>
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is very vague and would be a lot more useful to see the code in which you create the object and set it's material. The following code below is how you would set an object's material to wireframe. Hopefully this helps you, if not please add your code to your question as I mentioned.

Code to set material to wireframe:

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    wireframe: true
});
```

Read more about this [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshBasicMaterial)

Comment: the object is imported via asset item, and you could set the material both ways, the above answer fixed the issue, thanks.